# SteamBot get Item Quality

Tags: c#, steambot

I am trying to list items with SteamBot using there genericInventory class and I can list out all the items and the names of the items but not the quality or float of the item.

```
TradeManager tm = new TradeManager(Bot.ApiKey, Bot.SteamWeb);
Trade t = tm.CreateTrade(Bot.SteamUser.SteamID, steamId);

TradeOffer offer = Bot.NewTradeOffer(steamId);
GenericInventory GI = new GenericInventory(Bot.SteamWeb);

List<long> contextId = new List<long>();
contextId.Add(2);
GI.load(730, contextId, steamId);
foreach (GenericInventory.Item item in GI.items.Values)
{
    GenericInventory.ItemDescription ID = GI.getDescription(item.assetid);
    //SendChatMessage("App ID: " + item.appid + " ContextID: " + 
    //  item.contextid + " Asset ID: " + item.assetid);
    SendChatMessage(ID.name + "|" + ID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: You should include any relevant code you have.

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion.